# Recursive call to compare object properties

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

```
public static bool PropertiesEqual<T>(this T self, T other, string[] skip)
{
    if (self.Equals(other)) return true;

        var primitive = (from p in typeof(T).GetProperties() 
                         where !skip.Contains(p.Name) 
                         && p.PropertyType.IsSimpleType() 
                         select p).ToList();

        var rest = (from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                      where !p.PropertyType.IsSimpleType() select p).ToList();

        foreach(var pi in rest)
        {
            var selfValue = pi.GetValue(self, null);
            var otherValue = pi.GetValue(other, null);

            //var result = selfValue.PropertiesEqual(otherValue);

            if (!object.Equals(selfValue, otherValue))
                return false;
        }


        foreach (var pi in primitive)
        {
            var selfValue = pi.GetValue(self, null);
            var otherValue = pi.GetValue(other, null);

            return object.Equals(selfValue, otherValue);
        }

        return true;
}

public static bool IsSimpleType(this Type type)
{
    return (type.IsValueType || type.IsPrimitive || 
       type == typeof(String) || Convert.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object);
}
```

I'm using this method to compare equality on my entity instances. On the first level it works great, but I would like to iterate over `rest` (attached entities) and do a recursive call to this method (the comment line).

The problem seems to be that `self` and `other` gets typed in to `object` on the recursive call, hence `primitive` gets zero results. If I inspect the type on `self` and `this` on the first level, I get the actual type, but on the second level I get `object`. I've tried using the `Convert.ChangeType` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to have it generic. Instead of `typeof(T)` use `self.GetType()` / `other.GetType()` to retrieve the correct run-time type.

Comment: the type of self is not what is needed, instead, the type of pi is needed.

Comment: @oerkelens No, the types of `selfValue` and `otherValue` are needed. In the recursive call, those are the types of `self` and `other`.

Comment: we are talking about different moments in the code :) I now see what you mean. I just realised I edited my answeer to match yours. When you said "no reason to have "it" generic" i thought yuo meant the whole extension method, and that didn't make much sense. My bad :)

Comment: @Johan Not only is there no reason to be generic, it is a bad idea. Remember that a property of type `Mammal` can contain a `Giraffe`, having more properties than the `Mammel` type. This answer not only provides a simple solution, it is also functionally better than using generics.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change the self and other value assignments to this?

```
var selfValue = Convert.ChangeType(pi.GetValue(self, null), pi.PropertyType);
var otherValue = Convert.ChangeType(pi.GetValue(other, null), pi.PropertyType);
```

I noticed that although T becomes object, self and other are of the correct type. So instead of gettign yoru propertes from typeof(T), try this:

```
var rest = (from p in self.GetType().GetProperties() select p).ToList();
```

In my simple test it worked and returned the wanted props.
You might have to change more than this one line :)

Comment: +1 for actually noticing the problem, but as I said above, I've tried this without success :/

Comment: But what happened when you did that? Does selfValue keep being object, what is pi.PropertyType when you debug?

Comment: `pi.PropertyType` is the correct type, but when the recursive call is made and I enter the method again, it turns to `object`

Comment: type of selfValue before the recursive call is also object then? Then it seems convert is doing nothing :(

Comment: Strange, i'm testing, and it seems selfValue and otherVBalue are the correct type but somehow they do get cast to object on the call. I don't know why?

Comment: Hehe well, me neither. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

Way back, I did a comparerhelper and it allowed exclude properties.
Maybe code can help you:

```
public class CompareHelper
        {

            Hashtable reccorido = new Hashtable();
            List<IExcludeProperties> excludeProperties = new List<IExcludeProperties>();
            private readonly List<string> genericListPropertiesNames = new List<string>() { "Count", "Capacity", "Item" };
            public CompareHelper():this(new List<IExcludeProperties>())
            {

            }

            public CompareHelper(List<IExcludeProperties> excludeProperties)
            {
                this.excludeProperties = excludeProperties;
            }

            public bool AreEquals<T1, T2>(T1 value1, T2 value2)
            {
                try
                {
                    reccorido = new Hashtable();
                    return Compare(value1, value2);
                }
                catch (NotEqualsException ex)
                {
                    PropertyFail = ex.Where();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public string PropertyFail
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            private bool Compare<T1, T2>(T1 value1, T2 value2)
            {
                if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if ((value1 == null) || (value2 == null))
                {
                    throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                    //return false;
                }

                string key = GetKey<T1, T2>(value1, value2);

                if (reccorido.Contains(key))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                reccorido.Add(key, true);
                Type tipo1 = GetType(value1.GetType());
                Type tipo2 = GetType(value2.GetType());


                if (tipo1 != tipo2)
                {
                    throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                    //  return false;
                }


                if (IsBasicCompare(tipo1))
                {
                    return CompareBasic(ConvertTo(value1, tipo1), ConvertTo(value2, tipo1));

                }
                dynamic v1 = ConvertTo(value1, tipo1);
                dynamic v2 = ConvertTo(value2, tipo1);
                if (!CompareFields(v1, v2))
                {

                    throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                    //return false;
                }


                return CompareProperties(v1, v2);
            }

            private string GetKey<T1, T2>(T1 value1, T2 value2)
            {

                int hascodeA = value1.GetHashCode();
                int hascodeB = value2.GetHashCode();
                if (hascodeA > hascodeB)
                    return string.Format("{0}{1}", hascodeA, hascodeB);

                return string.Format("{0}{1}", hascodeB, hascodeA);
            }

            private dynamic ConvertTo(object value1, Type t)
            {
                if (value1 == null)
                    return null;
                return Convert.ChangeType(value1, GetType(t));
            }

            private bool CompareProperties<T>(T value1, T value2)
            {


                if (IsGenericList(typeof(T)))
                {
                    return ComparareGenericList(value1, value2);

                }
                List<PropertyInfo> properties = GetPropertiesToCheck<T>();
                foreach (var p in properties)
                {


                    try
                    {
                        var valueA = p.GetValue(value1, null);
                        var valueB = p.GetValue(value2, null);

                        if (!(valueA == null && valueB == null))
                        {
                            if (valueA == null || valueB == null)
                            {
                                throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                                // return false;
                            }

                            if (IsBasicCompare(p.PropertyType))
                            {
                                valueA = ConvertTo(p.GetValue(value1, null), p.PropertyType);
                                valueB = ConvertTo(p.GetValue(value2, null), p.PropertyType);


                                if (!CompareBasic(valueA, valueB))
                                {
                                    throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);

                                    // return false;
                                }

                            }
                            else if (IsEnumerable(p.PropertyType))
                            {

                                if (!CompareAsInumerable(valueA, valueB))
                                {
                                    throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                                    //   return false;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (p.PropertyType.IsClass)
                            {
                                if (!Compare(ConvertTo(p.GetValue(value1, null), p.PropertyType), ConvertTo(p.GetValue(value2, null), p.PropertyType)))
                                {
                                    throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                throw new Exception(string.Format("Tipo no especificado {0}", p.PropertyType));
                        }

                    }

                    catch (NotEqualsException ex)
                    {
                        ex.AddParent(p.Name);
                        throw;
                    }

                }
                return true;


            }

            private  List<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesToCheck<T>()
            {

                List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

                Type typeToCheck= typeof(T);
                IExcludeProperties exclude=excludeProperties.FirstOrDefault(excl=>excl.ExcludeType().IsAssignableFrom(typeToCheck));
                if(exclude!=null)
                    return typeToCheck.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && (!exclude.GetPropertiesNames().Any(n=>n==p.Name))).ToList();

               // 
                return typeToCheck.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead).ToList();


            }

            private bool ComparareGenericList<T>(T value1, T value2)
            {

                List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.Name != "Capacity").ToList(); //la capacidad no la compruebo!!


                PropertyInfo count = typeof(T).GetProperty("Count");

                int totalA = ConvertTo(count.GetValue(value1, null), count.PropertyType);
                int totalB = ConvertTo(count.GetValue(value2, null), count.PropertyType);

                if (!Compare(totalA, totalB))
                    return false;


                PropertyInfo item = typeof(T).GetProperty("Item");
                CompareAsInumerable(value1, value2);

                return true;

            }

            private bool IsGenericList(Type t)
            {


                return t.IsGenericType && IsEnumerable(t) && t.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead).Any(p => genericListPropertiesNames.Contains(p.Name));

            }
            [Conditional("DEBUG")]
            private void ShowInfo(PropertyInfo p)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Checkeando propiedad {0}",p.Name));
            }

            private bool CompareFields<T>(T value1, T value2)
            {
                List<FieldInfo> fields = typeof(T).GetFields().Where(f => f.IsPublic).ToList();

                foreach (var f in fields)
                {
                    dynamic valueA = f.GetValue(value1);
                    dynamic valueB = f.GetValue(value2);

                    if (!Compare(f.GetValue(value1), f.GetValue(value2)))
                    {
                        throw new NotEqualsException(value1, value2);
                        //return false;
                    }

                }
                return true;
            }


            private bool CompareAsInumerable<T>(T valueA, T valueB)
            {
                IEnumerable<object> colA = ((IEnumerable)valueA).Cast<object>();
                IEnumerable<object> colB = ((IEnumerable)valueB).Cast<object>();
                if (colA.Count() != colB.Count())
                    return false;

                Type t1 = GetType(colA.GetType());
                Type t2 = GetType(colB.GetType());

                if (t1 != t2)
                    return false;

                if (colA.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Type itemType = GetTypeOfItem(colA);

                    for (int i = 0; i < colA.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dynamic a = colA.ElementAt(i);
                            dynamic b = colB.ElementAt(i);

                            if (!Compare(a, b))
                            {
                                throw new NotEqualsException(colA.ElementAt(i), colB.ElementAt(i));
                                //return false;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (NotEqualsException ex)
                        {
                            ex.AddParent(itemType.Name);
                           throw ;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            private Type GetTypeOfItem(IEnumerable<object> collection)
            {

                if (collection == null)
                    return null;
                Type[] t = collection.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

                if ((t != null) && (t.Count() > 0))
                    return t[0];
                return null;

            }



            private bool IsEnumerable(Type type)
            {
                return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
            }

            private bool CompareBasic<T>(T valueA, T valueB)
            {
                bool result;
                IComparable selfValueComparer;

                selfValueComparer = valueA as IComparable;

                if (valueA == null && valueB != null || valueA != null && valueB == null)
                    result = false;
                else if (selfValueComparer != null && selfValueComparer.CompareTo(valueB) != 0)
                    result = false;
                else if (!object.Equals(valueA, valueB))
                    result = false;
                else
                    result = true;

                if (!result)
                    throw new NotEqualsException(valueA, valueB);
                return result;


            }
            private bool IsBasicCompare(Type type)
            {
                return typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(type) || type.IsPrimitive || type.IsValueType;
            }


            private Type GetType<T>()
            {
                return GetType(typeof(T));
            }
            private Type GetType(Type t)
            {
                Type tipo = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
                if (tipo == null)
                    tipo = t;
                return (tipo == null) ? t : tipo;
            }


        }
```

Helper class:

```
 public interface IExcludeProperties
    {
        Type ExcludeType();
       void  AddPropertyName(string propertyName);
        List<string> GetPropertiesNames();
    }

  public class ExcludeProperties<T> : IExcludeProperties
    {
        HashSet<string> propertiesNames = new HashSet<string>();

        List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>();


        public ExcludeProperties()
        {
            props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList();
        }

        public Type ExcludeType()
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }

        public void AddPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            if(! typeof(T).IsAbstract &&  !props.Any(p=>p.Name==propertyName) )
                throw new Exception(string.Format("No existe y no por lo tanto no se puede excluir la propiedad {0} para el tipo {1}!",propertyName,typeof(T).Name));


              propertiesNames.Add(propertyName);
        }

    public List<string> GetPropertiesNames()
    {
        return propertiesNames.ToList();
    }
}
```